# What is the purpose of having two login managers on one system ?

Tags: init, display-manager, login-manager

I read, that the first process born in user-space is called **Init**, it starts by itself further processes, it also possesses an incorporated **login manager**. So far, I could understand it, but than I read, that many **display managers** are either just another name for login manager or incorporate such one.

So, many systems have **two login managers** running in user-space, one in Init and one in a Display manager of their choice.

What is the reason for having two of them? 
Which one is the one Users login with usually?

Answer (score 1):

There are different incarnations of `init`, including SysVinit, Upstart, and systemd. But I doubt if any of them incorporates a **login manager**, whatever that is. It may *spawn* other processes that offer logins:

- on terminals including the console and serial ports, so that users can log in on those terminals (`getty`)
- on a graphical display, for local logins with X11 sessions (display managers like `xdm`, `lightdm`, etc...)
- remotely over the network (e.g. `sshd`)

`init` also spawns many other things that have nothing to do with logins.

Generally there is no contradiction among the many services that `init` or scripts called by `init` will spawn.

Comment: See `man systemd-logind`...

Comment: @jasonwryan Aha, I see. Another systemd "innovation", I guess! I guess that makes my answer kind of incorrect.